# name 'c' is not defined in python

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I tried to make a calculator with Django, but got this error

This view function takes the input from html page and performs the calculation.

Where is the problem here?

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def indx(request):
    template = loader.get_template('calculator/calc_home.html')

    if request.method=='POST':
        global c, a, b
        a = request.POST.get('num1')
        b = request.POST.get('num2')

        option = request.POST.get('select_val')

        if a == "" or b == "" :
            c = 'please select 2 numbers'
        else:   
            if option == 'add':
                c = int(a) + int(b)
            elif option == 'multiply':
                c = int(a) * int(b) 
            elif option == 'substract':
                c = int(a) - int(b)
            elif option == 'devide':
                if int(b) + 0 == 0:
                    c = 'infinity'
                else:   
                    c = int(a) / int(b)         
            else:
                c = 'please choose an option'   

    context = {
        'sum': c,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

### calc_home.html

html code takes the input and passes it to the view

```
<h1>welcome to calculator</h1>

<p>enter 2 numbers</p>

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="num_1">enter 1st number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="num1" value='num_1'><br>
    
    <label for="num_2">enter 2nd number:</label>
    <input type="number" name="num2" value='num_2' ><br>
    
    <input type="radio" value="add" name="select_val" id="add" >
    <label for ="add">+</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="substract" name="select_val" id="subs" >
    <label for ="subs">-</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="multiply" name="select_val" id="multiply" >
    <label for ="multiply">*</label><br>
    <input type="radio" value="devide" name="select_val" id="devide" >
    <label for ="devide">/</label><br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit">
</form>
    
<h1>{{ sum }}</h1>

<br><a href="{% url 'home:homex' %}">go to home</a>
```

### Error

This error is coming in the html page

```
name 'c' is not defined

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/calculator/
Django Version: 4.0.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'c' is not defined
```

what should be done to get rid of this error?

Comment: Using globals inside of a view, i can't see any reason for any of them to be global

Comment: Other than that you can see that you're request method is a GET and most of the view is not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need `global`s here (why do you think you do?)
2. Your problem stems from `c` not necessarily always having a value due to how your ifs are nested. (`c` doesn't get assigned any value if the request method isn't POST, and you still try to use it in the template context.)
3. You should never need to use `loader.get_template()` in regular use.

You'll have a better time if you refactor your code to use a plain old function to do the calculation, and call that in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def do_calculation(a, b, option):
    if not (a and b):
        return 'please select 2 numbers'
    if option == 'add':
        return int(a) + int(b)
    if option == 'multiply':
        return int(a) * int(b)
    if option == 'substract':
        return int(a) - int(b)
    if option == 'devide':
        if int(b) + 0 == 0:
            return 'infinity'
        return int(a) / int(b)
    return 'please choose an option'


def indx(request):
    result = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST.get('num1')
        b = request.POST.get('num2')
        option = request.POST.get('select_val')
        result = do_calculation(a, b, option)

    return render(request, 'calculator/calc_home.html', {
        'sum': result,
    })
```

Beyond these improvements, you should look into Django's forms to further DRY out your code.